# What determines entries in "Lost & Found" in Kubuntu 16.04?

Tags: kubuntu, kde

System: Kubuntu 16.04 with kubuntu-backports enabled (KDE Plasma: 5.8.7 | KDE Frameworks: 5.36.0 | Qt: 5.6.1)

I see the image shown below:

[image: Kubuntu 16.04 Lost & Found]

What determines why there is an entry in the "Lost & Found" category? As far as I know, I haven't done anything at all with "Kirigami". Is there anything that needs to be fixed by me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### What does *Lost & Found* mean.

On other Desktop Environments it is probably called *Other* instead of *Lost & Found*. It just means, that your Desktop Environment could not figure out, where to put an application.

### Why are some applications in *Lost & Found*

The `.desktop` file of your application lacks the `Categories` option.
You can find it's location under multiple paths:

- `/usr/share/applications` (System wide)
- `/usr/local/share/applications` (System wide)
- `~/.local/share/applications` (User specific)

### Changing categories

If you don't like it you can change the category of the application with multiple ways.

**In KDE**

1. Right click your Application Menu
2. Click *Edit Applications...*
3. Expand *Lost & Found*
4. Drag the entries to a different category (In this example it would be *Development*)
5. (optional) Sort the category

   1. Right click the category
   2. Click *Sort...*
   3. Click *Sort selection by name (or description)*.
6. Click the *Save* button.

**In GNOME or GTK+ based desktops**

You will probably need to install a tool called `alacarte`.

1. Install `alacarte` (`apt-get install alacarte`)
2. Open `alacarte` by typing it in your terminal or via menu (Note that it is called *Menu Editor* on most systems)
3. Move the items around
4. Save

**Editing the file (Advanced)**

1. Find your file (located in a folder described above)
2. Open it in your desired text editor (for exampel `nano`)
3. Add `Categories=MyCategory`
4. Save the file.

---

The name was probably derived from the folder called `lost+found` that appears on unix like systems. 
More information about `lost+found` can be found (no pun intended) here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18154

Comment: If you wish you could point out that `/usr/share/applications/org.kde.kirigami.gallery.desktop` lacks a `Category` entry.

Comment: @DKBose I edited my post to add your recommendation